# How to create tabs filter based url with react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Actually, I want to try a tabs-based URL. When I click tabs the tabs store on URL by params like
https://example.com/filter?tabs=review.when I refresh this page same tabs data is shown. please help me how can I create tabs-based URLs with react js?
or my codeSandbox link here https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-spence-5zmw5n?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import useUrlState from "@ahooksjs/use-url-state";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const [currenturl, setCurrenturl] = useState(0);
  const Data = [
    {
      title: "left",
      content: "loremleft",
    },
    {
      title: "right",
      content: "loremright",
    },
  ];
  const { active_tabs } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className=""
        style={{ display: "flex", margin: "5px", justifyContent: "center" }}
      >
        {Data.map((i, idx) => (
          <a
            key={idx}
            className={active_tabs === idx ? "active" : ""}
            style={{ margin: "5px" }}
            onClick={() => {
              if (active_tabs !== setCurrenturl(idx)) {
                navigate(`${idx}`);
              }
            }}
          >
            {i.title}
          </a>
        ))}
      </div>

      {/* <div>
        {currenturl == 0
          ? "contethere"
          : currenturl == 1
          ? "2ndcontent here"
          : "blacnk"}
      </div> */}
      <p>
        <p activeTabs={active_tabs}>{Data[currenturl].content}</p>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please add codeSandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-spence-5zmw5n?file=/src/App.js
 This is my codeSandbox link

Comment: Thank you. What is your exact requirement? what is the expected behavior on refresh ?

Comment: actually, my requirement, I have two tabs 1- lefttabs 2-righttabs .  when I click lefttabs then lefttabs show in the URLs like https://example.com/lefttabs,because when I share URLs another person and opens only the same URL-based tabs.
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-spence-5zmw5n?file=/src/App.js please visit this site . Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted. You want to store the state value in the url.

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useURLState( '0',   'pathParam');
  const Data = [
    {
      title: "left",
      content: "loremleft"
    },
    {
      title: "right",
      content: "loremright"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className=""
        style={{ display: "flex", margin: "5px", justifyContent: "center" }}
      >
        {Data.map((i, idx) => (
          <div
            key={idx}
             className={activeTab === idx ? "active" : ""}
            style={{ margin: "5px" }}
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveTab(idx)
            }}
          >
            {i.title}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <p>{Data[activeTab] && Data[activeTab].content}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function useURLState(initialState,paramsName)
{

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const param = useParams();
  const existingValue = param[paramsName];
  const [state, setState] = useState(
    !!existingValue ? existingValue: initialState
  );
  useEffect(() => {
  if (existingValue && existingValue  !== state) {
      setState(existingValue);
    }
  }, [existingValue]);

  const onChange = (s) => {
    setState(s);
    navigate(`/${s}`)
   
  };

  return [state, onChange];
}
```

Also in index.js

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/:pathParam" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

I have created a custom hook useURLState, so that it can be reused to store any state value in the url, just by using state and setState.

hope this helps!!